# Unable to fulfilling Stripe Connect representative requirement

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

im trying to create a company account via Stripe Connect. The problem is that whatever i do i always receive that there is missing representative. I'm attaching my JS code below.

Thanks in advance for the help people !

```
currently_due: [
    "representative.address.city",
    "representative.address.line1",
    "representative.address.postal_code",
    "representative.dob.day",
    "representative.dob.month",
    "representative.dob.year",
    "representative.email",
    "representative.first_name",
    "representative.last_name",
    "representative.phone",
    "representative.relationship.executive",
    "representative.relationship.title"
],
```

```
const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
    country: payload.country,
    type: 'custom',
    capabilities: {
      card_payments: {
        requested: payload.capabilities.card_payments
      },
      transfers: {
        requested: payload.capabilities.transfers
      },
    },
    business_profile: payload.business_profile,
    business_type: payload.business_type,
    tos_acceptance: {
      date: Math.round(+(new Date()) / 1000),
      ip: ip
    },
    company: {
      ...payload.company,
      directors_provided: true,
      executives_provided: true,
      owners_provided: true,
    },
    external_account: {
      object: 'bank_account',
      country: 'BG',
      currency: 'BGN',
      account_number: 'BG80BNBG96611020345678'
    }
  });
  const person = await stripe.accounts.createPerson(
    account.id,
    {
      ...payload.representative
    }
  );
  let updatedAccount = await stripe.accounts.retrieve(
    account.id,
  );
```

The person representative payload looks like this. All fields are filled according to documentation and the creation passes

```
representative: {
    first_name: document.getElementById('representative.first_name').value,
    last_name: document.getElementById('representative.last_name').value,
    email: document.getElementById('representative.email').value,
    phone: document.getElementById('representative.phone').value,
    ssn_last_4: document.getElementById('representative.ssn_last_4').value,
    dob: {
        month: document.getElementById('representative.dob.month').value,
        day: document.getElementById('representative.dob.day').value,
        year: document.getElementById('representative.dob.year').value,
    },
    address: {
        line1: document.getElementById('representative.address.line1').value,
        postal_code: document.getElementById('representative.address.postal_code').value,
        city: document.getElementById('representative.address.city').value,
        state: document.getElementById('representative.address.state').value,
    },
    relationship: {
        title: document.getElementById('representative.relationship.title').value,
        executive: document.getElementById('representative.relationship.executive').value === 'true',
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without being able to see any of the `payload` content, but are you setting any fields inside of `relationship` (when creating the person object) to `true` as mentioned in [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information#additional-information-on-the-representative)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer toby. I add the standard representative fields. My object looks like this ( all are following the documentation )

https://gist.github.com/DJilanov/459254da016f3288ddf6a5d52b558886

Comment: If you look at the request that created the person within your Stripe dashboard, do you see that `relationship.executive` is set to `true` in the request body?  If it is, then Stripe Support may be the best route to understand why that person isn't fulfilling the representative requirements.  If it's set to `false` then I'd take a closer look at that `===` comparator and make sure it's doing what you're expecting it to.